# boolean expression doesn't match

Tags: python

I having a simple issue which I don't seem to understand why,`force_edl` variable value is 'False" (its an option to my python script and user enters True or False)but the conditions `if force_edl == False:` and            `if not force_edl` doesnt seem to match,how do I debug this problem?below code always goes to else part...is there way to strip bool values?

```
        print "force_edl " + force_edl //prints false
        if force_edl == False:
        #if not force_edl
             print "False"
        else:
             print "True"
```

Comment: Is `force_edl` a string "False"? Or is it *actually* a `bool` type?

Comment: Are you confusing the string "False" with the Boolean value False?

Comment: It sounds like your variable is the _string_ "False" instead of the actual boolean value `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting it to a string, int or boolean when needed.  Right now your trying to use a boolean as a string which wont work.

```
enter code here
force_edl = int(False)
print "force_edl " + str(force_edl)
if force_edl == False:
         print "False"
else:
         print "True"
```

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot concatenate 'str' and 'bool'.** So if this

```
print "force_edl " + force_edl
```

is not giving you an error *then your force_edl is definitely not a bool.*

That's why **your if prints True**.

```
force_edl = False

if force_edl == False:
    print "FALSE"
else:
   print "TRUE"
```

Above corrected snippet will definitely print False.

Do let me know if this clears your doubt.